# How do you restrict the macOS windowing management from restoring a specific window?

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-windowgroup, nswindowrestoration

I have an app that has a few windows defined as a windows group in the structure conforming to App in the main scene:

```swift
WindowGroup("StandingsView") {
    
    StandingsView()
        .environmentObject(appServices)
}
.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "StandingsView"))
```

The appServices take some time to be configured, so I do not want to automatically restore the windows at start.  I create the windows upon user selections being valid, the services being fully configured, and the user pressing a 'start' SwiftUI button:

```swift
if let standingsURL = URL(string: "raceStratLiteApp://StandingsView") {
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(standingsURL)
}
```

I've tried closing the windows in the appDelegate's applicationShouldTerminate().
I've also tried setting the isRestorable to false in applicationShouldTerminate:

```swift
func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {
    
    for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
        window.isRestorable = false
    }
    return .terminateNow
}
```

Are there any other methods to not restore a window?  or better yet, to be able to programmatically restore it with its previous size, etc but launch only on user direction to 'start'

TIA

Comment: If you mean disable for always then just put into UserDefaults false for NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows key.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi. So its not a code change but an environment change that can be done by the installer.  I'll provide an answer based on your tip

Comment: No, it is possible to set in code, e.g. in app delegate on did finish launching via `UserDefaults.register(defaults:...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code solution as @Asperi suggests in the later comment:

```swift
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows" : false])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the tip provide by @Asperi, writing the following to defaults will cease the writing of the window states:

`$ defaults write <bundleid> NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false`

So this is not a code change to the app, but rather an environment config the would be done on install.

I also deleted the savedState directory located at `~/Library/Saved Application State/<bundleid>.savedState` for archive builds and at `~/Library/Containers/<App Name>/Data/Library/Saved Application State/<bundleid>.savedState` for debug builds.  Am not sure if that mattered but once doing these steps it solved the problem.  Thanks @Asperi